# how to set the icon uri from absolute url for ApplicationBarIconButton?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am quite familier with .NET and i have started developing for wp 8. I should create the application bar dynamically when running the app and i dont know how the hell i should set a icon for the ApplicationBarIconButton from an absolute url?
i have tried code below but got exception in add function. It perfectly works with relative path but not dynamically.

ApplicationBarIconButton btnCar = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("http://www.test.com/files/test.png", UriKind.Absolute));

btnCar.Text = "cars";
ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(btnCar);

Can anyone help me.
Tnx in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.applicationbariconbutton.iconuri(v=vs.105).aspx for more info

the icons have to be local. "The URI must point to a file in the application directory. When adding an image file to a project using Windows Phone SDK, you must set the Build Action property to “Content”. Using the default value “Resource” will not allow the image to be accessed or displayed."

have a look at roundbutton in http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/ toolkit. it looks like appbar button but is a normal button. so you should be able to use absolute uri based images.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i really have to access the icon dynamically.  Is there anyway to load the file and save it in application directory? so i do all dynamically. i have read about IsolatedStorageFile but that seems unhelpful for me since it doesnt save in app directory. Do you have any sugesstion?

Comment: i dont think so...  they have to be set as content. so they have to be present in app install path not in isostore

Comment: have a look at coding4fun's RoundButton